# How can i make these shapes different in loop with python?

Tags: python, loops

So I have this code here, everything is good but it has to make 20 different shapes, at the moment it makes 20 same shapes. Can somebody help me plz?

```py
import random
from turtle import*

def func(lenght, nr_of_sides):
    i = 0
    while i in range(20):
        i += 1
        for element in range(nr_of_sides):
            forward(lenght)
            angle = 360/nr_of_sides
            left(angle)

a = random.randint(1, 100)
b = random.randint(3, 10)
func(a, b)

exitonclick()
```

Comment: Give more info. What shapes do you need? What color? What size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the for loop out of the function so every time it starts a new iteration the `a` and `b` values are random.

```
import random 
from turtle import*

def func(lenght, nr_of_sides):
    for element in range(nr_of_sides): 
        forward(lenght) 
        angle = 360/nr_of_sides
        left(angle)


for i in range(0, 20):
    a = random.randint(1, 100) 
    b = random.randint(3, 10) 
    func(a, b)

exitonclick()
```

Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Well you're creating a and b as random values and you're passing them to your function. But once passed, the values won't change. Try putting the random.randint bits inside your while loop to have it generate a new random value with each iteration of the loop.